# vmware + ubuntu + docker = черный экран. Почему?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vmware

Хостовая ОС Windows 10

Использую VMware.Workstation.15.Pro.v15.5.1

Виртуальную машину создаю на базе ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop

На виртуальную машину ставлю Docker по этой инструкции https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/ (но способ установки ни на что не влияет, я перепробовал разные варианты, в том числе и через sudo apt install docker.io)

Все устанавливается нормально и работает нормально. Docker успешно запускает контейнеры. Но все работает только до первой перезагрузки виртуальной машины. А точнее, после того как нажал перезагрузить, машина начинает перезагружаться и зависает на черном экране. Дальше никакой реакции, так может висеть очень долго.

Я пробовал принудительно выключать питание виртуальной машины и запустить наново, но ничего не помогает. Начинается загрузка и опять зависает на черном экране.

Перезагрузка VMware.Workstation тоже не помогает.

Все начинает работать только после перезагрузки самого хостового компа. После этого запускаю VMware.Workstation и на ней запускаю виртуалку Ubuntu c Docker-ом. Все запускается, все работает, но опять же до первой перезагрузки виртуалки, или до второго запуска. Дальше опять черный экран и так по кругу.

В чем может быть причина? Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема. После установки VMware tools все работает отлично.

Прикладываю ссылку с инструкцией по установке:

https://losst.ru/ustanovka-vmware-tools-ubuntu-18-04